# (oracle) SELECT (that returns more than one row) inside DECODE

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

I'm trying to write a DECODE statement with SELECT inside it which will look like this:

```
SELECT DECODE(A.name, (SELECT name FROM B WHERE id IN (1000,1001)),'Value1','Value2') FROM A
```

Obviously if my select statement inside DECODE returns more than one row I will get an exception "ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row". Which is fair enough.

I'm expecting to get more than one row there, this is the purpose, and I need to display Value1 for all of the items that match A.name and Value2 for those that don't. Like foreach loop but inside DECODE.

What is a proper way of doing it?

Update:
Table A:

```
+--------------+--------+
|Surname       | Name   |
+--------------+--------+
|           Abc| John   |
|         Smith| Piter  |
|          Cook| Ann    |
+--------------+--------+
```

Table B:

```
+--------------+--------+
|ID           | Name   |
+--------------+--------+
|         1000| John   |
|         1001| Piter  |
|         2003| Ann    |
+--------------+--------+
```

What I expect to see:

Value1

Value1

Value2

Comment: Please show table definitions, sample data, and expected output.

Comment: please show full query. What is A and B and is there any relation between them?

Comment: Can you  have more than one row in B with the same name?

Comment: Aleksej, no. I will give more details a bit later, to make the question more clear - with table examples and expected results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this situation you might use the CASE statement:

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN 
          a.name in (select name from b where id in (1000, 1001)) then 'Value1' 
         ELSE 'Value2' 
   END 
 FROM a;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this with an inner join:

```
-- Test case setup
CREATE TABLE A(SURNAME, NAME) AS
SELECT 'Abc', 'John'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Smith', 'Piter' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Cook', 'Ann'    FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE B(ID, NAME) AS
SELECT 1001, 'John'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1002, 'Piter' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2003, 'Ann'   FROM DUAL;

-- Solution
SELECT CASE WHEN B.ID IN (1001, 1002)
            THEN 'Value1'
            ELSE 'Value2'
       END Value
  FROM A, B
 WHERE A.NAME = B.NAME
```

Results:

```
VALUE
------
Value1
Value1
Value2
```